# LINQ to objects: Is there a way to pass to LINQ the accessor from which to get values?

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, linq-to-objects

I cannot seem to find a way to have LINQ return the value from a specified accessor.
I know the name of the accessors for each object, but am unsure if it is possible to pass the requested accessor as a variable or otherwise achieve the desired refactoring.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
// "value" is some object with accessors like: format, channels, language
row = new List<String> {
String.Join(innerSeparator, (from item in myObject.Audio
    orderby item.Key ascending
    select item.Value.format).ToArray()),
String.Join(innerSeparator, (from item in myObject.Audio
    orderby item.Key ascending
    select item.Value.channels).ToArray()),
String.Join(innerSeparator, (from item in myObject.Audio
    orderby item.Key ascending
    select item.Value.language).ToArray()),
// ...
}
```

I'd like to refactor this into a method that uses the specified accessor, or perhaps pass a delegate, though I don't see how that could work.

```
string niceRefactor(myObj myObject, string /* or whatever type */ ____ACCESSOR) {
    return String.Join(innerSeparator, (from item in myObject.Audio
            orderby item.Key ascending
            select item.Value.____ACCESSOR).ToArray());
}
```

I have written a decent amount of C#, but am still new to the magic of LINQ. Is this the right approach? How would you refactor this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `Func<AudioType, object>` to select the property you want:

```
string niceRefactor(myObj myObject, Func<AudioType,object> propertySelector)
{
    return String.Join(innerSeparator, (from item in myObject.Audio
                                        orderby item.Key ascending
                                        select propertySelector(item.value)).ToArray());
}
```

This assumes that `AudioType` is the type of the value items returned by the Audio key value pairs.

You can then call your method e.g. like this:

```
string result = niceRefactor(myObject, x => x.format);
```

Comment: how will he call this function ?please supply sample

Answer (score 4):

I'd extract the most obvious commonality to start with:

```
var audioItems = myObject.Audio.OrderBy(item => item.Key);
row = new List<String> {
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Format).ToArray());
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Channels).ToArray());
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Language).ToArray());
}
```

If I were using .NET 4, I'd then remove the `ToArray` calls as `string.Join` has more overloads now:

```
var audioItems = myObject.Audio.OrderBy(item => item.Key);
row = new List<String> {
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Value));
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Format));
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Channels));
    String.Join(innerSeparator, audioItems.Select(x => x.Language));
}
```

I *might* stop there. But if you wanted, you could always add another extension method:

```
public static string Separate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, items);
}
```

Then:

```
var audioItems = myObject.Audio.OrderBy(item => item.Key);
row = new List<String> {
    audioItems.Select(x => x.Value).Separate(innerSeparator));
    audioItems.Select(x => x.Format).Separate(innerSeparator));
    audioItems.Select(x => x.Channels).Separate(innerSeparator));
    audioItems.Select(x => x.Language).Separate(innerSeparator);
}
```

I'd almost certainly stop there. You *could* keep going:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ProjectAndSeparateMany<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, string separator, Func<T, object>... projections)
{
    return projections.Select(projection => items.Select(projection)
                                                 .Separate(separator);
}
```

And call it with:

```
var audioItems = myObject.Audio.OrderBy(item => item.Key);
row = audioItems.ProjectAndSeparateMany(innerSeparator,
         x => x.Value, x => x.Format, x => x.Channels, x => x.Language).ToList();
```

... but at that point it's *so* specialist, I doubt that I'd ever use it again...

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to refactor this into a method that uses the specified accessor, or perhaps pass a delegate, though I don't see how that could work.

You could do this using the object syntax and passing a delegate (This is assuming that your `.Value` is of type `MyValueType`):

```
string NiceRefactor(MyObj myObject, Func<MyValueType, string> accessor)
{
     return string.Join(innerSeparator, myObject.Audio.OrderBy(m => m.Key).Select(m => accessor(m.Value));
}
```

Using this, you can write:

```
// "value" is some object with accessors like: format, channels, language
row = new List<String> {
    NiceRefactor(myObject, v => v.format),
    NiceRefactor(myObject, v => v.channels),
    NiceRefactor(myObject, v => v.language),
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
// "value" is some object with accessors like: format, channels, language
row = new List<String> {
    JoinProperties(myObject.Audio, innerSeparator, x => x.format),
    JoinProperties(myObject.Audio, innerSeparator, x => x.channels),
    JoinProperties(myObject.Audio, innerSeparator, x => x.language),
// ...
}


...


public string JoinProperties<TKey, TValue, TProperty>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, string separator, Func<TValue, TProperty> selector)
{
    return string.Join(separator, dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(kvp => selector(kvp.Value)));
}
```